# how to use my phone's Dolby audio processor as my laptop's sound card?

Tags: audio, sound-card

I've got an HTC One M9 and the audio processor on it is way better than my laptop .

So what I'm tryina do here is to let my phone do all the sound processing but I actually don't have any idea if it's possible or not.

has anyone ever tried doing such thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution and it was pretty easy.

here it is : https://www.senstic.com/android/pocketaudio/pocketaudio.aspx

So what it does is make a server on your Windows/Mac and stream all the sounds coming from your PC to your phone . it also installs a sound driver on your PC so make sure you install it too. ( windows firewall might block the streaming so you need to make an exception for that program on windows )

You need to download the app for Android/IOS as well. ( instructions on the link )

and the sound quality was awesome so now my phone is an External Wireless Sound Card for my Windows PC.

the only problem is that you might have a 2-3 sec delay but I really don't mind.